# How to deal with Page while unit testing with mockito and Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I want to mock database call with fake data but I got stuck in the following scenario:

MyService

```java
public class MyService {
    // some stuff

    Page<SampleDto> sample = repo.findAllSample();

    // other stuff
}
```

I want to stub this with `when()` but I am not able to do this. My test is:
MyServiceTest

```java
public class MySampleTest {

    @Test
    void myTest() {
        // initialisation and all stuff

        when(myRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(......)
        // I want to pass 2 fake SampleDto from 
        // here but don't know how to do that
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock the `Page` object also if there is a aneed to handle some other functionality inside your service class. Assuming that your service class is actually something like:

```
public class MyService {
    @Resource
    private SampleRepository repo;

    public Page<SampleDto> findAllSample() {
        var sampleData = repo.findAllSample();
        // perhaps some operations with sample data and page
        return sampleData;
    }
}
```

then the test class could be something like (JUnit4):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MySampleTest {
    @Mock
    private SampleRepository repo;
    @Mock
    private Page<SampleDto> page;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
    doReturn(page).when(repo).findAll();
    var listSampleDtos = List.of(new SampleDto()); // populate with what you need
    doReturn(listSampleDtos).when(page).getContent();
    var page = myService.findAllSample();
    // ... do the asserts, just as an example:
    verify(repo).findAll(); // called
    assertEquals(1, page.getContent().size());
    }
```

Comment: As I already commented on Ravan's answer: Having mocks return other mocks is a bad idea.

Comment: @EricSchaefer Ok, maybe. Never had any problems. Used `@Mock` & `@Spy` without any problems as mocks mocks answers. Would be glad if you could link some resource to see possible probs? Will it mix mockito somehow?

Comment: I don't have a link handy. It is also more of a general observation. Mocks returning mocks can often lead to weird error cases (especially when using a mocking library), because of all the "magic" involved. Apart from this, it usually is a hint that the general design might need improvement. e.g. The only reason why you would mock the Page is, that it is an external type that is hard to work with (i.e. because it is JPA). This also means that the service should not even know Page. Wrap the JPA repo and have the wrapper return a List or Set instead of a JPA-Page.

Comment: Thank you @pirho for excellent  and deeply explanation of above question. I got what I want Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are two main directions for resolving such types of tasks:

1. Fake objects
2. Mocking

**Fake objects** approach is plain implementation of your repo without any third-party libs for lightweight/simple cases:

```java
public class FakeRepo implements Repo<T> {
   private final Collection<T> all;

   public FakeRepo(){
      this(Collections.emptySet());
   }

   public FakeRepo(Collection<T> all){
       this.all = all;
   }

   @Override
   public Collection<T> findAll(){
       return this.all;
   }
}
```

and in your test  may looks like

```java
@Test
public void justdoit(){
   MyService service = new MyService(
       new FakeRepo(Arrays.asList(1,2))
   );
   // test the service & methods
}
```

**Mocking** allows you to make much more complex solutions.
Please make attention on methods `Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class)` and `Mockito.spy(new ArrayList<String>())`. You need to assemble your complex objects using Mockito engine like
https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations

```java
@Test
public void whenNotUseMockAnnotation_thenCorrect() {
    List mockList = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);
    
    mockList.add("one");
    Mockito.verify(mockList).add("one");
    assertEquals(0, mockList.size());

    Mockito.when(mockList.size()).thenReturn(100);
    assertEquals(100, mockList.size());
}
```

or

```java
@Test
public void whenNotUseSpyAnnotation_thenCorrect() {
    List<String> spyList = Mockito.spy(new ArrayList<String>());
    
    spyList.add("one");
    spyList.add("two");

    Mockito.verify(spyList).add("one");
    Mockito.verify(spyList).add("two");

    assertEquals(2, spyList.size());

    Mockito.doReturn(100).when(spyList).size();
    assertEquals(100, spyList.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lazylead I appreciate your nice solution with mocking and spying.

Answer (score 1):

Just create what you want to be returned and pass it to `thenReturn()`.

In your case it could look like this:

```java
// I making this up, because you did not state what 'Page' actually is
var result = new Page();
result.add(new SampleDto(1));
result.add(new SampleDto(2));
when(myRepo.findAllSample()).thenReturn(result);
```

You might not be able to do this, depending on the actual implementation of `Page`, for instance if this is a JPA `Page`. In this case you should not really return `Page` into your Service anyway, but wrap the JPA repository into a adapter repository that returns a `List<SampleDto>` or `Set<SampleDto>` instead. Otherwise your Service, which belongs to the Domain, would depend on an implementation detail of infrastructure code like JPA, which is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the page and make sample object. May be this is the exact answer you are searching.

MySampleTest

```
public class MySampleTest {

@Test
void myTest() {

    // initialisation and all stuff

    List<SampleDto> sampleDtos = new ArrayList<>();

    //now add any number of sample dto
    dtos.add(new SampleDto());

    //mock page class here
    Page page = mock(Page.class);

    //stub page.getContent
     when(page.getContent()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(sampleDtos));

    // No need to do this  when(myRepo.findAll()).thenReturn()
  
}
```

}

Comment: In general, it is a bad idea to have mocks return other mocks. If anything breaks in the tested code you will have a fun time finding the cause.